# php curl execution time limitation

Tags: php, curl, settings

While using PHP I am taking image links from my mysql database, and echoing them out. There are 600 or so, but it keeps stopping after running 100 or so. It is not a logic error, it seems there is a setting that is stopping php from continuing the curl. Please advise which setting I should expand to allow a longer CURL thanks!

Here is what I am using now:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
return $data;
}

$htmlaa = file_get_contents_curl($getimagefrom);
$docaa = new DOMDocument();
@$docaa->loadHTML($htmlaa);
```

Again, it is worknig just fine but just keeps stopping after running for maybe 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the curl timeout like so:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);  //seconds to live`

Since there are multiple factors that influence execution time you should also check out these two as well:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Also please note that `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` defines the amount of time that any cURL function is allowed to take to execute. You should also checkout `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` option.

Comment: I added set_time_limit(0); to top of document but it still stops at same point each time. :(

Comment: set_time_limit does not seem to be the problem here. Did you investigate the other timeout options?

Comment: I put curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200000); still not working :(

Comment: please help i have no idea what to do